# Do adjectival prepositional phrases introduced by "with" have a specific name/type (translation of "complément circonstanciel d'accompagnement")?

Tags: translation, prepositional-phrases, adjectival-phrases

How do you analyze/translate a "complément circonstanciel d'accompagnement" or can you further specify the type of *adjectival prepositional phrase* introduced by *with* (or *which has*) this is? Here are some examples of what I'm talking about (from [this source](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)):

> *Un chapeau à fleurs*  [a hat with/which has flowers]
> *Une robe à carreaux* [a dress with/which has "tiles" i.e. a check dress]
> *Une femme aux yeux de braise* [a woman with/which has ember eyes]

*Fleurs*, *carreaux*, *yeux de braise* are what "comes with" the hat/flowers/woman so to speak hence the word "accompagnement" (accompaniment).

Comment: A hat with flowers - *with flowers* is a prepositional phrase. It acts adjectivally. It has no special designation. -- 

A hat which/that has flowers – *which/that has flowers* is a relative clause – this also acts adjectivally. It has no special designation.

Comment: A description of a noun that uses _with_ usually means that the noun _has_ (in its possession sense) whatever the object of _with_ is.  So _a hat with flowers_ is a hat that has flowers, _a man with a troubled past_ has a troubled past, _a woman with 3 kids_ has more than two children, and so forth.

Comment: The question is slightly misguided as it relies a bit too much on the French grammar. The context is [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52468). I have this type of complement and I'm trying to provide insight for the English speakers, which is why I'm trying to figure out if I can add something more to _adjectival prepositional phrase_. It is only about those contexts which use the preposition to add a feature to the noun. Introducing _which has_ (the relative) was a mistake (_À_ introduit un complément d'accompagnement.− _À_ signifie « avec », « qui a »). It's better to just explain.

Comment: Pronouns in both English and French have a wide variety of uses. There are many different uses of "[with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with)" (possession, opposition, association, agent, instrument, possession, support/agreement, object, place...) and just because some things are expressed with "à" in French doesn't mean they forms a single class in English. In particular "with blue eyes" indicates possession while "with a checked pattern" indicates composition.

Comment: @StuartF I hear you completely and never thought otherwise. It's just scope is challenging.

Comment: In English, *the man with green eyes* and *the man in the iron mask* aren't viewed as at all similar beyond the fact that they're prepositional phrases, even though, if I understand correctly, they are both *compléments circonstanciels d'accompagnement* in French grammar.

Comment: @PeterShor Quite possibly, although it wouldn't be the case with _l'homme masqué de fer_ where it would just be an _épithète_ (I guess) but this collocation would be quite unusual/rare compared with ones using _au/avec_ indeed.

Comment: @StuartF "indicating composition" is most likely what I was after here, even though it doesn't equate the idea of _accompagnement_. It is most likely the feature which would help provide a further cue to _adjectival prepositional phrase_ along the lines of what the _accompagnement_ refers to in context. The exact sentence was _Une fleur au pistil prudent_. To me it's about structure.

Comment: @StuartF Interesting that both can be replaced with similar adjectival forms: "green-eyed man" and "checked dress".

Answer (score 1):

> Do adjectival prepositional phrases introduced by "with" have a specific name/type (translation of "complément circonstanciel d'accompagnement")?

I don't think there is a set or agreed-upon phrase / name / categorisation for prepositional phrases.

The problem is that, because of the etymology of "with", "with noun phrase" has (at least) three meanings.

I opened the door with my key - "with" has an instrumental meaning.

"I went to London with John" - "with" has a meaning of accompaniment.

"John lost his temper with David and fought with him." = with has the meaning of "against" -> oppositional

Comment: Isn't it still an NP containing a PP? To simplify  NP Det N PP P NP ?   [[A [hat [with flowers]]]] being one.  *Groupe nominal* works almost the same way.  All about the ambiguity with those prepositions in English but not so much in French.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'French Language'?  Obviously we could speak of a 'flowered' or 'floral' hat.  It is simply in the nature of language itself that they they can approach the same idea differently. These differences are among the most interesting things about foreign languages.

Comment: The context comes from the French language site from an answer of mine. In the end just explaining what this is about is more useful than finding an exact type for something which doesn't have the same scope in English etc. The question is more about how to provide a cue to a non native speaker and what's the thing that comes as close as possible to something they know, without overdoing it like I did in the Q. It's a difficult balancing act. It's further compounded by the fact I'm very unfamiliar with the grammar lexicon in English and even basic grammatical analysis. Thanks.